# Slow charging, random wake-up and dead USB connections

Tags: usb, charging, asus-zenfone-5

My phone, Asus Zenfone 5 (A501CG), takes too much of time to charge (6-7 hours).
Also, the screen wakes up randomly every 5 seconds (approx.).
The phone doesn't connect to a PC (it's not recognized) and OTG doesn't work either.

In Settings, it shows that the phone is charging on USB even when it's charging on AC.

It happens in safe mode too.

What can be the issue? Can a faulty micro-USB port cause this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the micro USB keeps disconnecting slightly and reconnecting. This will cause the screen to wake up, because your screen will wake up when charge state changes (discharging, charging, and full battery). Additionally if the USB disconnects slightly, your phone may register as being connected and charging as the USB was not fully disconnected, at least on my phone. The reason you probably can't connect it with your computer is because your phone isn't connected long enough for the computer to recognize it. Try a diffrent cable. If this works, then the old cable was faulty, and shouldn't be used with your phone.

Comment: I tried another cable too, but it still didn't work. I'll get it's USB port changed now.

Comment: It could also be the USB connection on your phone.